# SQL Server referential integrity add rows parent table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a parent table

```
ptable (pid int, name varchar(10)); where pid is the primary key
```

and

```
Child table ctable (pid int, cid int, cname varchar(10)); where pid references ptable.
```

`ptable` has only 2 rows

```
pid   name
1     Sales
2     Marketing
```

Using C# application I am inserting rows into `ctable` from a text file. I want to be able to create a row in `ptable` if referential integrity is violated. Can this be done and how?

Comment: Look into the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Use Triggers in SQL Server.

Comment: If someone adds a record in Ctable with a PID which doesnt exist in PTable you can add that PID in Ptable 1st before adding it to Ctable but what Name value would you add in Ptable for that New PID ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an *INSTEAD OF INSERT* trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_insert_ctable
ON ctable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    Insert Into ptable
    Select i.pid, '??'
    From inserted i
    Where not exists ( Select * From ptable p where p.pid = i.pid )

    Insert Into ctable
    Select * From inserted
END;
```

Comment: THanks everyone. Instead of creating a trigger, I created a stored procedure with the above code from @thepirat000 and had to add other functionality to it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, this can be done with a trigger or other ways.  You said you are doing this via a text file.  The only way that I've been able to do this is importing the text file into a temp table, and validating the data including parent/child integrity rules.  A simple "select count(id) as total from ptable where pid :=pid" before doing your child insert would tell you if the parent record exists.  You could then either do one insert for the parent table followed by an insert for the child (if not exists) or you could go straight to inserting the child record if the parent existed.

Some systems have a dummy parent record that is used if a parent record isn't found for the initial insert and second field stores a unique id temporarily.  The missing parent record is then created and the child record updated.  The child table is then updated to the correct value similar to "UPDATE child_table.parentid where some_field = mytempvalue".  I usually end up using an existing text field for my temporary storage and then update both the parentId and the text field to the correct values.